How to use nav2 in a known environment and read information from apriltags
I’m very new to robotics so any help is appreciated.
I have a project where I need to have an autonomous robot capable of autonomously navigating a known environment and has apriltag detection (they’re like QR codes) in order to read information from the tags.
I decided to look into ROS in order to do this, and while I’ve made some progress (I found an apritag detection package, I simulated a robot, I launched the map of the environment). I am stuck on the nav2 aspect and the best way to implement it. I’m using ROS Humble.
I’m also stuck on how to receive data from the apriltag detection and have the nav2 package receive it and move accordingly.
I know ROS is complicated and has a great learning curve, so I wonder if it’s the best option for this project? Or if there is something easier that can be used?
Or is there a simple way to achieve my goal in ROS that I am not aware of?
Any help is appreciated greatly thank you.
